# What's the simplest way to make an Illusion of a password?

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

I need some help... I have an input and a button, and I need the button to redirect to another page only if the password is right. there will be only one password so I would love the simplest solving (js will be perfect). I will be really happy if you help me. thank you!

```
<img id="login" src="pics/log-in.png" >
  <form action="main.html"> 
     <input type="password" placeholder="password">  
     <button type="submit">enter</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: I'd like to point out to Vitaly that this approach is extremely insecure.

Comment: Could you provide more context on what you are using? Do you have a backend to authenticate the user? Are you using a front end framework or is this a simple html and JS site?

Comment: There's no backend, and this site is basically a school project and I only need the frontend. I need this password not for security reasons but as a part of a gameplay

Answer (score 1):

First step is to create an on click listener on the button. If the password is correct, inside the button listener add the follwing line of code:

```
window.location.href="url_of_another_page";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (reasonably) secure way to do that:

```js
let SECRET_URL = 'U2FsdGVkX1+d04CGQMFLvfPtMXpNIyl9sosbT07swnH9nRgL0EY3xLQkW8ukVZXR'

function go() {
  let pwd = document.querySelector("#password").value;
  let url = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(SECRET_URL, pwd).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  alert('redirecting to ' + url);
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<input id="password">
<input type=button onclick='go()' value="login">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Unless you enter a valid password (which happens to be `fish`), the redirect address won't be revealed. It's also impossible to find it out from the source code.

To create an encrypted url like the above, use

```
SECRET_URL = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my url', 'my password').toString()
```